# fixing my hide default and show/hide when it is mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My show/hide mouseover is working good and my only problem is by defult when i refresh the page it shows my span class that i want it to by default hide. How can i edit my code to make it definitely hide it by default. I already added in my display:none in my css and when i tried it, this code hide definitely and disable my javascript in show/hide mouseover. By the way i am in wordpress environment and i was looping it because it is a post.

So all i want is to make it default: hide using this code below

Here is my code something like this:

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php
if( $projectsBlog->have_posts() ) : ?>
<div class="container">
<ul class="image">
    <div class="row row-centered">
    <?php while ( $projectsBlog->have_posts() ) : $projectsBlog->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-box1" onMouseOver="show_title<?php echo $count ?>()" onMouseOut="hide_title<?php echo $count ?>()">

        <li class="top-featured-image">
        <span class="effect" id="hoverli<?php echo $count ?>"><?php the_title( sprintf('<a href="%s">', esc_url(get_permalink())),'</a>'); ?></span>

        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

        </div>
    <?php if($count==2) :
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="row row-centered">'; 
    endif; ?>
    </li>
    <?php $count++; endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

here is my javascript i made it one by one because it was looping :

```
function show_title0(){
  document.getElementById('hoverli0').style.visibility="visible";
}
function hide_title0(){
  document.getElementById('hoverli0').style.visibility="hidden";
}

function show_title1(){
  document.getElementById('hoverli1').style.visibility="visible";
}
function hide_title1(){
  document.getElementById('hoverli1').style.visibility="hidden";
}

function show_title2(){
  document.getElementById('hoverli2').style.visibility="visible";
}
function hide_title2(){
  document.getElementById('hoverli2').style.visibility="hidden";
}

function show_title3(){
  document.getElementById('hoverli3').style.visibility="visible";
}
function hide_title3(){
  document.getElementById('hoverli3').style.visibility="hidden";
}

function show_title4(){
  document.getElementById('hoverli4').style.visibility="visible";
}
function hide_title4(){
  document.getElementById('hoverli4').style.visibility="hidden";
}

function show_title5(){
  document.getElementById('hoverli5').style.visibility="visible";
}
function hide_title5(){
  document.getElementById('hoverli5').style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

here is my css with display attribute where i tried only one li class but the default hidden doest display all:

```
#hoverli0 {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: `visibility:hidden;` will hide, but hold the Element's place. `display:none;` will not hold the Element's height and width. I'm not seeing any CSS using a `.class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating seperate functions for each elements create two generalize functions as below. And to hide and show you should have to use `display:none` and `display:block` as below.

```
function show_title(id){
    document.getElementById('id').style.display="block";
}

function hide_title(id){
    document.getElementById('id').style.display="none";
}
```

And pass the id of element in the php code as below.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-box1" onMouseOver="show_title('hoverli<?php echo $count ?>')" onMouseOut="hide_title('hoverli<?php echo $count ?>')">
```

In this way you can achieve by only two functions no need of redundant functions.

Comment: Why using javascript for this? With the [CSS :hover Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_hover.asp) this is done with two simple css rules. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For this you don't need javascript. I think the [CSS :hover Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_hover.asp) is here the right choice.

You can hide the `span`by default with `display: none;` or with `visibility: hidden;`(with `visibility: hidden;` the element will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout).

**Example:**

```css
ul.image li span.effect {
  display: none;
}

ul.image li:hover span.effect {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="image">
 <li class="top-featured-image">
  <span class="effect">span content</span>
  -image-
 </li>
 <li class="top-featured-image">
  <span class="effect">span content</span>
  -image-
 </li>
 <li class="top-featured-image">
  <span class="effect">span content</span>
  -image-
 </li>
 <li class="top-featured-image">
  <span class="effect">span content</span>
  -image-
 </li>
 <li class="top-featured-image">
  <span class="effect">span content</span>
  -image-
 </li>
 <li class="top-featured-image">
  <span class="effect">span content</span>
  -image-
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, use `toggleClass` in a single query.

If you would like to do it using jQuery only, you can compress your code and do it in a simple way by using following query.

```
//Hide all the span by default
$('li.top-featured-image > span').addClass('hide');
//Use mouse enter and leave events in a query
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.top-featured-image',function(){
   $(this).find('span').toggleClass('show hide');
});
```

```js
$('li.top-featured-image > span').addClass('hide');
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.top-featured-image',function(){
  $(this).find('span').toggleClass('show hide');
});
```

```css
.show
{
  display: block; 
} 
.hide
{
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="image">
 <li class="top-featured-image">
  <span class="effect">span content1</span>
  -image-1
 </li>
 <li class="top-featured-image">
  <span class="effect">span content2</span>
  -image-2
 </li>
 <li class="top-featured-image">
  <span class="effect">span content3</span>
  -image-3
 </li>
 <li class="top-featured-image">
  <span class="effect">span content4</span>
  -image-4
 </li>
 <li class="top-featured-image">
  <span class="effect">span content5</span>
  -image-5
 </li>
 <li class="top-featured-image">
  <span class="effect">span content6</span>
  -image-6
 </li>
</ul>
```